# Why the difference between Tomcat and Tomcat7 regarding servlet mapping and defaults?

Tags: java, localhost, tomcat

With the following configuration:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then both Tomcat7 and Tomcat6 serves the following URL just fine: `http://127.0.0.1:8087/mynet/index.html`

However, if I reduce the configuration to just mention the CSS pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then Tomcat6 works, but Tomcat7 fails with: The requested resource () is not available.

Why is there a difference here?

Comment: Because they decided to change it?

Comment: If I do not add any “default”  。Access http://127.0.0.1:8087/mynet/index.html Success。 tomcat7 ，tomcat6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** map container's `default` servlet in your webapp's `web.xml`. Whatever functional requirement for which you thought that this is the solution, it has definitely to be solved differently.

If you have for example overridden it with a custom front controller servlet on an URL pattern of `/`, then you should fix that servlet to listen on a more specific URL pattern instead. Use if necessary a filter to "hide" the servlet's specific URL pattern by collecting all static resources in a single folder such as `/static` or `/resources` and letting the filter check on that.

#### See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872050/404-error-accessing-static-content-when-defualt-servlet-is-defined-in-web-xml
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513